# issue when I switch to second page in xcode (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm pretty much brand new to using both swift and xcode, and I've been having a problem switching between two view controllers (as shown in the video). Whenever I press the button to go to the next screen, the blue bar at the bottom shows up and it stops working. It worked before, but after I added a third and fourth view controller it stopped working. I don't know where the problem would be, so I'm not sure what parts of my code to send but I can send whatever is needed.

the video of my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvFkltNAJkI&feature=youtu.be

This is the code for my second ViewController (the one that opens when schedule is pressed)

```
import UIKit
protocol DataDelegate {
    func insertEvent(eventString: String, pos: Int)
    func insertDate(_ dateString: String, pos: Int)
    func insertImage(_ matImage: UIImage, pos: Int)
}
class SecondScreenViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, DataDelegate {

    @IBAction func back()
    {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    var dates = ["6/1/20", "6/3/20", "6/3/20"]
    var eventNames = ["event1", "event2", "event3"]
    var images = [UIImage(named: "Test"), UIImage(named: "Test"), UIImage(named: "Test")]
    var mImage = UIImage(named: "TestTree")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        perform(#selector(advance), with: nil, afterDelay: 2)

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "FirstTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "FirstTableViewCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    //DataDelegate methods
    func insertEvent(eventString: String, pos: Int)
    {
        if pos == -1
        {
            eventNames.append(eventString)
        }
        else
        {
            eventNames.insert(eventString, at: pos)
        }
    }
    func insertDate(_ dateString: String, pos: Int)
    {
        dates.insert(dateString, at: pos)
    }
    func insertImage(_ matImage: UIImage, pos: Int)
    {
        images.insert(matImage, at: pos)
    }

    @objc func advance()
    {
        let vc = NewCellViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        present(NewCellViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //TableView Funcs
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return dates.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstTableViewCell
        //method calls to sort dates (move names with them) before displaying, in this class
        cell.myDate.text = dates[indexPath.row]
        cell.myEventName.text = eventNames[indexPath.row]
        cell.myImageView.image = images[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

I'm using this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqL0n.png) segue to present the view controller, but the problem didn't start occurring until I created the segue to the view controller at the bottom, which is weird because I did not do anything to trigger it on the first two screens.

Comment: Post the code here.

Comment: Alright, I added the code for the second viewcontroller, please let me know if anything else is needed :)

Comment: Show how you are presenting this controller.

Comment: alright I just added the image

Comment: @Picode I'm not sure how to reply to a post on this website but thank you so much, this fixed my issue

Comment: You are welcome, happy coding :) @JacquelineEdwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem because of iOS 13. Change your `viewController's presentation style` as `Full Screen`.

Also if you have a `navigation controller`, you must set your `navigation controller's presentation style` as `Full Screen`.

[image]

Hope it helps...

Comment: How is this gonna fix the button disabled state?

Comment: I don't understand your question @Frankenstein